# How to implement 850 svg files - resource oder assets?

Tags: android, kotlin, svg, resources, assets

My project in Android Studio needs 850 svg files.

Now is the question how import the files.

I thought of resource as R.drawable.image1 ... but is it possible to create a
custom folder in drawable?

Is it a better way to implement the files in an newly created asset folder?

I use

```
val imageUrl = "file:///android_asset/bland/image1.svg"
```

but android studio did not find the directory

Any help?

Comment: "My project in Android Studio needs 850 svg files" -- the Android SDK does not support SVG. You will either need to convert those to vector drawables or use a library that supports SVG. "is it possible to create a custom folder in drawable" -- no. "Is it a better way to implement the files in an newly created asset folder?" -- if you are using a library that supports SVG, and it supports assets, that should be fine.

Comment: I'm, using coil

Comment: Coil supports that `file:///android_asset` syntax for assets, so that part is fine. What specifically do you mean by "android studio did not find the directory"?

Comment: Only error in logcat is Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.lkprg2023/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory tried wipe in emulator but did not vanish - tried know following code  val imageUrl = "/android_asset/bland/swhol.svg"


        AsyncImage(
            model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(imageUrl)
                .build(),
            contentDescription = "Image",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Inside,
            )
but stays the same no error but no picture

Comment: Have you [enabled Coil logging](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/faq/#how-do-i-enable-logging)?

Comment: no - dont know how to ... looked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72981927/coil-image-caching-not-working-with-jetpack-compose and https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/api/coil-base/coil.util/-logger/index.html but dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Works ... here is my code ... (bland is my new asset folder)

```
val imageUrl = "file:///android_asset/bland/nomap.svg"


    AsyncImage(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(imageUrl)
            .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())
            .build(),
        contentDescription = "Image",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Inside,
        )
```

Works for

```
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.4.0")
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:2.4.0")
```